# How to change the default font size in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, default, font-size

I'd like to know if it is possible to change some default parameters of `ggplot2` graphics, like font size for instance, for a whole R session. The idea is to avoid setting them for each plot.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use `theme_set()`

```
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 18))
qplot(1:10, 1:10)
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful! In case anyone is interested, the default text size is **11** (`theme_gray()$text$size`)

Comment: under new ggplot2 2.2.1 I do not see `base_size` under theme listed but it seems to work. I noticed my `geom_text` for showing text of a mean is not inheriting this base_size change. Anyone have luck with getting this to work

Answer (score 63):

Use `theme_set` if you want to update for the remainder of your active session:

```
theme_set(theme_grey(base_size = 18))
```

If you only want to change one graph you can set the `base_size` in the theme:

```
qplot(1:10, 1:10) + theme_grey(base_size = 18) 
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + 
geom_point() +
theme_grey(base_size = 18)
```