# Rstudio: how to control default point size in plots?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there an Rstudio-specific way to specify the default font size?  Since Rstudio has other panels that use up space, I'd like to have a smaller font size than I would have for other ways of using R.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools | Options | Global Options`. There you can set the font. As far I can tell this persists between sessions.

Also see [here](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/customizing).

RE @Dank's note: sorry, I see now that you mentioned plots in the question.

I think this cannot be controlled globally in RStudio, but depends on the specific graphics package you are using. So using plot(...) in base R you would use:

```
par(ps=10)   # default starts out at 12
```

This sets the default point size to 8 points until you use par(...) again.

If you are using ggplot, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955229/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  I meant the font for graphics, akin to the ``point size`` argument for e.g. ``x11()``.

Answer (score 0):

You may use teh parameter cex , for example

```
cex=0.7
```

it decreases the font relatively to the default font.