# How to change the default font size in ggplot2 - including geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, font-size

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955229/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-in-ggplot2) was great to set a base size for all my plots in R Markdown docs, which I usually work in (e.g., `theme_set(theme_grey(base_size = 18))`. However, as someone eluded to in the comments, `geom_text()` does not inherit `theme_set()`. Have any suggestions?

I am open to completely different ideas for managing font size in ggplot plots in R Markdown. FYI, I usually knit to Word and then upload to Google Drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geom_text` indeed doesn't inherit `theme_set()`. See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-text.r) how we have `size = 3.88` set directly. However, the same source code suggests to use the following.

```
GeomText$default_aes$size <- 1
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars))) + geom_text()
```

[image]

Now this works only for `geom_text`, but I don't think it's a good idea to set the same size for every single thing anyway (axes text, titles, etc.). However, it seems to be analogous with others geoms, e.g.,

```
GeomLabel$default_aes$size
# [1] 3.88
```

**Update**: there seems to exist a formal function doing basically the same:

```
update_geom_defaults("text", list(size = 10))
```