# Edit legend labels from within a factor call in ggplot ()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm learning R and I created a basic `ggplot()` with the code below:

```
ggplot(aes(ACTIVITY_X, ACTIVITY_Y, color = as.factor(cluster), shape = Event)) + geom_point(size=3) + xlab("Axis X") + ylab("Axis Y") + labs(color="Cluster") + labs(shape="Dominant behaviour") 



p + theme_classic()
```

This is an actual picture of it:
[image]

I would like to edit the labels below `Cluster`, so that they become `"Standing"`,`"Feeding"` and `"Foraging"`.

How can I edit labels from a factor call? I've tried this earlier with no luck:

```
+   ggplot(aes(ACTIVITY_X, ACTIVITY_Y, color = as.factor(cluster,
+                                                        labels = "Standing", 
+                                                                               "Feeding", "Foraging"))
+              , shape = Event) +
+   geom_point(size=3) + xlab("Axis X") + ylab("Axis Y") + labs(color="Cluster") + labs(shape="Dominant behaviour")
> 
>         
> 
> p + theme_classic()
Error in as.factor(cluster, labels = "Standing", "Feeding", "Foraging") : 
  unused arguments (labels = "Standing", "Feeding", "Foraging")
```

Also, I would like to increase the size of all text in the plot, including axis labels and legends.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Don't use `as.factor()`, just use `factor()` and all your labels need to be in a vector, not separate parameters. For example `factor(cluster, labels=c("Standing", "Feeding","Foraging"))`

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you, that worked. How can I increase the size of the legend though from within a `factor()` call (and other text as well)?

Comment: Legend size comes from `theme` arguments; it's got nothing to do with creating a factor

Comment: You should just ask one question at a time with a Stack Overflow post. This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407773/increase-legend-font-size-ggplot2) will probably help with resizing legends, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955229/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-in-ggplot2) for all text.